# Can I have more than 1 UITabBarController?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

Lets imagine the scenario:

UITabBarController
- UITabBar
  - Tab 1: View Controller A
  - Tab 2: View Controller B

When I click on View Controller A I want to push another UITabBarController:

UITabBarController
-UITabBar
  - Tab 1: View Controller 1
  - Tab 2: View Controller 2
  - Tab 3: View Controller 3

Is this possible? To have a UITabBarController push another UITabBarController onto the view stack?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can certainly do this but I would rethink your design. Selecting a UITabBar item and changing the Tab Bar itself goes against [Human Interface Guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/UIElementGuidelines/UIElementGuidelines.html). Besides, in your example, how do you get back to the root view controller?

Perhaps you should use a UITableView that when you tap a cell it pushes a view controller containing a UITabBarController (technically this might go against HIG too since a tab bar should be the same throughout an entire app but I've had plenty of apps adopt this and it seems elegant). So using your example:

RootViewController:
pushed as UINavigationController with a UITableView containing two cells:
"cell1" & "cell2"

-Tapping on "cell1" pushes a view controller containing UITabBar(I) which contains "View Controller A" and "View Controller B."

-Tapping on "cell2" pushes a view controller containing UITabBar(II) which contains "View Controller 1," "View Controller 2," and "View Controller 3."

In each case, you get a "back" button and the UITabBar itself doesn't have to change.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the HIG flaw. I think I will need to rethink the design of my app!

Answer (score 0):

Sure, I just stacked them up in interface builder. There's some frame offsetting issues, but you can see tabbars stacked up. Additionally, the tabbars unstack when other tabs are selected. I also had to make sure the first tab's view was added to the window's view and connected as an `IBOutlet`, but otherwise that should do it.

[image]

Comment: hmm thats pretty ugly IMO. Is there a way when I push the the new UITabBarController it replaces the old ones tabs with new ones?